# Script for deleting files starting with texts listed in a file

Tags: bash

I have a strings.txt file that contains a list of strings like this:

```
0100101
0100102
0100103
0100104
...
```

I need to create a script that deletes all the files in a directory, starting with each of the strings contained in the previous file.

If there are files with these names in the directory, they should be deleted:

```
0100101.jpg
0100101-01.jpg
0100101A1.jpg
```

If there are files with these names in the directory, they should not be deleted:

```
40100101.jpg
570100102.jpg
340100104-02.jpg
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: `xargs` might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of cat and xargs to achieve this

```
cat strings.txt | xargs -t -I{} sh -c 'rm {}*'
```

More Info on xargs: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html

Comment: You can simplify it: replace `cat strings.txt |` with `< strings.txt`

Comment: I've tried your solution and give errors like this:

*  -c rm 00101
rm: cannot remove '00101\r*': No such file or directory

Comment: Your file has DOS line endings. Fix it with `dos2unix` or better yet don't use Windows at all.

Comment: Thank you, I used sed to solve it and now the command works perfectly. thank you all.